# RecyclerView blank even after data loads

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, swiperefreshlayout

I'm working on a `RecyclerView` within a `SwipeRefreshLayout`, which contains `CardViews` based on data retrieved from an API Call. This is implemented in a `Fragment` in one App and directly in the `Activity` in the other.

While this code (with appropriate modifications) works fine in the `Activity`, the variant in the fragment always shows blank - even though I have validated that the data is received. Even seeding a dummy `CardView` doesn't get anything to show up.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

**The initialisation in OnCreateView is as follows:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.fragment_revive_housecall, container, false);
    ...
    ...
    constraintLayout = view.findViewById (R.id.constraintLayout);
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById (R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById (R.id.recyclerView);
    emptyView = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.empty_view);
    houseCallList = new ArrayList<> ();
    adapter = new HouseCallAdapter (getActivity ().getApplicationContext (), houseCallList);
    if(houseCallList.isEmpty ()) {
        emptyView.setText (R.string.pulltorefresh);
        recyclerView.setVisibility (View.GONE);
        emptyView.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        //emptyView.setVisibility (View.GONE);
        recyclerView.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager (new LinearLayoutManager (getActivity ().getApplicationContext ()));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator (new DefaultItemAnimator ());
    recyclerView.setAdapter (adapter);
    adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {

        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            checkEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
            checkEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            super.onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart, itemCount);
            checkEmpty();
        }

        void checkEmpty() {
            emptyView.setText (R.string.no_data_available);
            emptyView.setVisibility(adapter.getItemCount() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility (adapter.getItemCount() == 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback = new RecyclerItemTouchHelper(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT /*| ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT*/, this);
    new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener (new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener () {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            loadHouseCallRequests(null);  // in this function call onItemsLoadComplete when done
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

**The OnSwiped override is as follows:**

```
@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction, int position) {
    if (viewHolder instanceof HouseCallAdapter.MyViewHolder) {
        // get the removed item name to display it in snack bar
        String housecallid = houseCallList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getHousecallid ();

        // backup of removed item for undo purpose
        final HouseCall deletedItem = houseCallList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        final int deletedIndex = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

        // remove the item from recycler view
        adapter.removeItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
            ((HouseCallAdapter.MyViewHolder) viewHolder).viewBackground.setBackgroundColor (getResources ().getColor (R.color.bg_row_background_decline));
            // showing snack bar with Undo option
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(constraintLayout, "Request " + housecallid + " declined!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackbar.setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    // undo is selected, restore the deleted item
                    adapter.restoreItem(deletedItem, deletedIndex);
                }
            });
            snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);
            snackbar.show();
        }
    }
}

void onItemsLoadComplete() {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}

private void loadHouseCallRequests(@Nullable JsonObject params) {
    // This is the code that generates the dummy cardview
    /*HouseCall call = new HouseCall ("abc123", "open", "12/02/1991", "26/02/2018:22:39", "general", "6", "XY", "AB", "ACB@XZY.com", "Male", "Line1", "Line2", "Line3", "City", "State", "123456789");
    houseCallList.add (call);*/

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    onItemsLoadComplete ();
    if (params == null) {
        params = new JsonObject ();
        params.addProperty ("email", email);
    }
    GetHouseCalls calls = new GetHouseCalls ();
    calls.execute (params);
}
```

**The Adapter**

```
public class HouseCallAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HouseCallAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<HouseCall> houseCallList;

private static final int DATASET_EMPTY = 0;
private static final int DATA_AVAILABLE = 1;


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView txtFname, txtLname, txtDob, txtSex, txtAddress, txtMobile;
    public ConstraintLayout viewBackground, viewForeground;


    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super (itemView);
        txtName = itemView.findViewById (R.id.txtName);
        ... // add data to the layout of the 
    }

}

public HouseCallAdapter(Context mContext, List<HouseCall> houseCallList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.houseCallList = houseCallList;
}


@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ())
            .inflate (R.layout.housecall_request, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder (itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    HouseCall houseCall = houseCallList.get (position);
    ... // retreive data from UI elements and set data in UI
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return houseCallList.size ();
}

public void removeItem(int position) {
    houseCallList.remove(position);
    // notify the item removed by position
    // to perform recycler view delete animations
    // NOTE: don't call notifyDataSetChanged()
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public void restoreItem(HouseCall item, int position) {
    houseCallList.add(position, item);
    // notify item added by position
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}
}
```

**Recycler Item Touch Helper**

```
public class RecyclerItemTouchHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
private RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener listener;

public RecyclerItemTouchHelper(int dragDirs, int swipeDirs, RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener listener) {
    super(dragDirs, swipeDirs);
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
    if (viewHolder != null) {
        final View foregroundView = ((HouseCallAdapter.MyViewHolder) viewHolder).viewForeground;

        getDefaultUIUtil().onSelected(foregroundView);
    }
}

@Override
public void onChildDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView,
                            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
                            int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    final View foregroundView = ((HouseCallAdapter.MyViewHolder) viewHolder).viewForeground;
    getDefaultUIUtil().onDrawOver(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY,
            actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
}

@Override
public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    final View foregroundView = ((HouseCallAdapter.MyViewHolder) viewHolder).viewForeground;
    getDefaultUIUtil().clearView(foregroundView);
}

@Override
public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView,
                        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
                        int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    final View foregroundView = ((HouseCallAdapter.MyViewHolder) viewHolder).viewForeground;

    getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY,
            actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
}

@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    listener.onSwiped(viewHolder, direction, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
}

@Override
public int convertToAbsoluteDirection(int flags, int layoutDirection) {
    return super.convertToAbsoluteDirection(flags, layoutDirection);
}

public interface RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener {
    void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction, int position);
}
}
```

**The layout xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.testapp.appname.FragmentCards">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/no_data_available"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.698"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: can you show your api call response method ?

Comment: give `wrap_content` to height of recylerview.

Comment: @MohammedFarhan thanks for the idea - I fixed the issue by looking at the layout XML - I realized that with the existing layour, RecycleView was not visible at all, and thats why the screen was blank on refresh

Comment: @hamza the api response is fine - it works in my other app, and this is a module from there

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @MohammedFarhan's suggestion, I looked at the XML layout for the UI, and found the problem there.

In the older layout, the RecyclerView was being hidden and was not visible on screen, hence the blank screen on the phone.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.testapp.appname.FragmentCards">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/no_data_available"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.698"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

All I needed to do to make it visible was to add a constraint from the top of the RecyclerView to the parent, and move the TextView to be a child of the ConstraintLayout.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.testapp.appname.FragmentCards">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="92dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/no_data_available"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498" />

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! :)